# Is it possible to access bing vision programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, bing

Hey I was wondering if it was possible to spin up Bing vision from within my application and get the returned picture.

I know I can spin up the camera, but is it possible to spin it up with the bing lense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open `lenses` only as this [Windows Phone app](http://dreamteam-mobile.com/blog/2014/04/bing-vision-cortana-wp81-qr/) (that opens Bing Vision).

Use this code to open LensPicker:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-lenspicker:{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5685}", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: Yes, I found that others were doing it, but I wanted to integrate it into a game. Can you say how I open bing Vision programmatically, because I have not been able to find an API for it.

Comment: I will test it later or tomorrow, to verify and give you the check mark :)