# WP8 QR scan solution for App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to launch another App from one APP

So, I need to scan a QR code, and do something with the code.

There are 2 type of solution,

1. Launch an QR code reader app from current app, scan, and return.

But I don't know it's possible or not.

2. Porting Zxing

Then hook up Zxing with the camera in WP

So I want to know is solution 1 possible?
Where I can find a sample about launch an app from an app

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application from another application.

For example

`Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("viber:"));`

But it's impossible to pick just so the results from another application.

Better for you to embed the code in your application to read.

There are libraries. For example, [ZXing.Net 0.14.0.1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many libraries out there in order to use the `QR Scanning`, where [this](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/wpqr-control/) sample from Wilcox could be helpful. Another option you could go with is to use the `ZXing.Net.Mobile` client for `QR` scanning. 
[Sample](http://www.davidbritch.com/2014/07/qr-code-scanning-in-windows-phone-app.html)

Why don't you try launching the `Bing Vision` from your app in order to do the scanning?

[Is it possible to access bing vision programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227962/)